# Node, express y Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una api de series, para eso arme el siguiente modelo:

```
const serieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    serie_posterImg: { type: String },
    serie_title: { type: String },
    serie_airing: { type: Boolean },
    serie_aired: {
        serie_from: { type: String },
        serie_to: { type: String }
    },
    serie_rating: { type: String },
    serie_score: { type: Number },
    serie_broadcast: {
        serie_day: { type: String },
        serie_time: { type: String },
        serie_timezone: { type: String },
        serie_string: { type: String }
    },
    serie_seasons: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Season'
    }],
    serie_genres: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Genre'
    }]
});
```

estos son los controladores para el serieSchema:

```
const getAllSeries = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const serie = await serieModel.find();
        res.send(serie);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}

const getSerieById = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        req = matchedData(req);
        const serie = await serieModel.findById(req.id);
        res.send(serie);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}

const addSerie = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const body = matchedData(req);
        const serie = await serieModel.create(body);
        res.send(serie);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}


const updateSerie = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const body = matchedData(req);
        const serie = await serieModel.findByIdAndUpdate(body.id, body);
        res.send(serie);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}

const deleteSerie = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        req = matchedData(req);
        const serie = await serieModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.id);
        res.send(serie);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}
```

y estos son mis otros 2 schema para las temporadas y los generos:

```
const seasonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    serie_airdate: { type: String },
    serie_episodes: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Episode'
    }],
    serie_seasonNumber: { type: Number }
});
```

```
const genreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    serie_name: { type: String }
});
```

ahora mis dudas son, como deberia hacer para que se muestre tanto todas las temporadas y sus episodios, como los generos al usar el **getSerieById**, es decir, recibir algo asi:

```
{
    "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8d8",
    "serie_posterImg": "url aca",
    "serie_title": "The Walking Dead",
    "serie_airing": false,
    "serie_aired": {
        "serie_from": "2010-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "serie_to": "2018-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "serie_rating": "PG 16",
    "serie_score": 8.2,
    "serie_broadcast": {
        "serie_day": "Sunday",
        "serie_time": "21:00",
        "serie_timezone": "GMT+1",
        "serie_string": "Sunday 21:00 GMT+1"
    },
    "serie_seasons": [
        {
            "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8d9",
            "serie_airdate": "2010-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
            "serie_seasonNumber": 1,
            "serie_episodes": [
                {
                    "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8da",
                    "serie_airdate": "2010-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "serie_episode": 1,
                    "serie_name": "Days Gone Bye",
                    "serie_synopsis": "Sheriff Deputy Rick Grimes wakes up from a coma to learn the world is in ruins, and must lead a group of survivors to stay alive.",
                    "serie_duration": 60,
                    "serie_thumbnail": "url aca"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8db",
                    "serie_airdate": "2010-11-07T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "serie_episode": 2,
                    "serie_name": "Guts",
                    "serie_synopsis": "Rick and the group are forced to take shelter in a barn, where they",
                    "serie_duration": 60,
                    "serie_thumbnail": "url aca"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8db",
            "serie_airdate": "2011-10-16T00:00:00.000Z",
            "serie_seasonNumber": 2,
            "serie_episodes": [
                {
                    "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8dc",
                    "serie_airdate": "2011-10-16T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "serie_episode": 1,
                    "serie_name": "What Lies Ahead",
                    "serie_synopsis": "Rick and the group are forced to take shelter in a barn, where they",
                    "serie_duration": 60,
                    "serie_thumbnail": "url aca"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8dd",
                    "serie_airdate": "2011-10-23T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "serie_episode": 2,
                    "serie_name": "Bloodletting",
                    "serie_synopsis": "Rick and the group are forced to take shelter in a barn, where they",
                    "serie_duration": 60,
                    "serie_thumbnail": "url aca"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "serie_genres": [
        {
            "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8de",
            "serie_name": "Acción"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8df",
            "serie_name": "Drama"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a9b1b9e3c4d1d0014a5c8e0",
            "serie_name": "Horror"
        }
    ]
}
```

y como deberia de cambiar el controlador para **agregar** los **generos a una serie**, y las **temporadas a una serie**.

Tambien como deberia hacer para que al entrar a la ruta del genero de accion por ejemplo, me muestre todas las series que tengan esa categoria, es decir que los **generos puedan tener multiples series**, y las **series tengan multiples generos**. gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya están referenciados, debería ser algo así.

```javascript
const serie = await serieModel.findById(req.id).populate('serie_seasons').exec()
```

Comment: y para agregar un genero ya creado, a una serie tengo que agregar algo al controlador de addSerie? o crear uno nuevo?